# Java Calendar.roll and CST during daylight saving changes

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, dst

I wonder if Calendar.roll respects its javadoc contract:

Running the following snippet

```
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));
    cal.setTimeInMillis(1457928024812l);

    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    cal.roll(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, true);
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

yiels the following output:

```
Sun Mar 13 23:00:24 CDT 2016
Sun Mar 13 23:00:24 CDT 2016
```

The 13 of March 2016 was a Daylight Saving change at 2 am (from CST to CDT).
The javadoc of roll states that roll "*adds a single unit of time*", and here no units of time is added.
Is it the expected behavior of this method?

EDIT:

I reported this as a bug. For more information, here is the link to the corresponding OpenJDK ticket: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8152077

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an actual bug in the `roll` method.  Nice find!

A couple of notes:

- I had to use a `SimpleDateFormat` to get the exact results you showed, as just calling `getTime` will give a `Date` object that prints in the local time zone.
- It would be better to use `America/Chicago` rather than `CST`, but that is not the cause of this.
- For any regular date, it rolling the 23rd hour should go to hour 0 on the same day.  If you wanted to just increment by an hour, then use `add` instead of `roll`.  See [add vs roll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2504141/634824).  The `add` method appears to be working correctly.
- On the day of a spring-forward transition, there are only 23 hours in the day.  The `roll` method appears to be taking this into account even though it did not cross over the actual transition (which occurs approaching 2:00 in this time zone, when the clocks jump ahead to 3:00).  As you showed, it set the hour to `23`, which is one hour before the `0` it should have set.
- On the day of a fall-back transition, there are 25 hours in the day.  Again, the `roll` method tries to take this into account, setting the hour to `1` instead of `0` even though it did not cross the actual transition (which again occurs approaching 2:00 in this time zone, when the the clocks move back to 1:00).

I did a quick search to see if this has been reported anywhere already and didn't find much.  Perhaps you should [report it](http://bugs.java.com/).

I'll also add that you should probably consider using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for Java 7 or earlier, and [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) for Java 8 or newer.

Comment: Thanks Matt. About the `America/Chicago` thing, I used `CST` simply to reproduce the issue. It occurred on a server with its default timezone, using a simple `Calendar.getInstance()`.

Answer (score 1):

As [the Answer by Matt Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35994645/642706) said:

- Use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the `continent/region` format. Avoid the 3-4 letter codes that are neither unique nor standardized.
- Use the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fdatetime%2FTOC.html). Avoid the old date-time classes, java.util.Date/.Calendar.

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCoordinated_Universal_Time) with [nanosecond](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FNanosecond) resolution. Apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
Long input = 1457928024812L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli ( input );

ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Chicago" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant, zoneId );

ZonedDateTime zdtHourLater = zdt.plusHours ( 1 );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " |  instant: " + instant + " | zoneId: " + zoneId + " | zdt: " + zdt + " | zdtHourLater: " + zdtHourLater );
```

> input: 1457928024812 |  instant: 2016-03-14T04:00:24.812Z | zoneId: America/Chicago | zdt: 2016-03-13T23:00:24.812-05:00[America/Chicago] | zdtHourLater: 2016-03-14T00:00:24.812-05:00[America/Chicago]

So, no such problem in java.time. Adding an hour moves across midnight as expected, from 11 PM on the 13th to just after midnight on the 14th.

### Daylight Saving Time (DST)

DST is handled properly.

#### Crossing the DST change-over

Adding one hour from 1:59 AM jumps two hours on the clock to 3:59 AM, as expected.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtBeforeTwoAm = ZonedDateTime.of ( 2016, Month.MARCH.getValue ( ), 13, 1, 59, 0, 0, zoneId );
ZonedDateTime zdtBeforeTwoAmPlus = zdtBeforeTwoAm.plusHours ( 1 );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "zdtBeforeTwoAm: " + zdtBeforeTwoAm + " |  zdtBeforeTwoAmPlus: " + zdtBeforeTwoAmPlus );
```

> zdtBeforeTwoAm: 2016-03-13T01:59-06:00[America/Chicago] |  zdtBeforeTwoAmPlus: 2016-03-13T03:59-05:00[America/Chicago]

#### Asking for 2 AM

Asking for 2 AM is not valid (no such time). So java.time automatically moves to a valid equivalent, 3 AM.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtTwoAm = ZonedDateTime.of ( 2016, Month.MARCH.getValue ( ), 13, 2, 0, 0, 0, zoneId );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ("zdtTwoAm: " + zdtTwoAm );
```

> zdtTwoAm: 2016-03-13T03:00-05:00[America/Chicago]