# Is there anything in the java.time package that does the same thing as the roll method in java.util.Calendar?

Tags: java, java.util.calendar, java-time

I am currently ditching all usages of java.util Date implementations from my project and want to change everything to Classes from the `java.time` package.

Now I found a usage of the **roll** method of a `java.util.Calendar` object and I am wondering how I can change this to something from the `java.time package`.

I checked if the date classes of java.time have a roll method, but I could not find any.

```
    ZonedDateTime.now().roll(); // method does not exist
    LocalDateTime.now().roll(); // method does not exist
    LocalDate.now().roll(); // method does not exist
```

I'm looking for something from the java.time package that does the same as the roll method from the `java.util.Calendar` class.

Somebody already asked a similiar question: [What is the equivalent of Calendar.roll in java.time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132085/what-is-the-equivalent-of-calendar-roll-in-java-time) But I find the accepted answer unsatisfactory. It does not answer whether there is something similar to roll in java.time or not.

Comment: In fact, the question is similar. But I find the accepted answer unsatisfactory. It does not answer whether there is something similar to roll in java.time or not.

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: The first thing I would do is check whether the `Calendar.roll` method was being used correctly. There are very few legitimate uses in the real world.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I talked now with a coworker about this specific code where roll was used. And he said that they only used roll, because of the absence of a .minus() method. So they only used it to subtract time _without the actual need of the behaviour of roll_, which doesn't change larger fields.

Comment: @zingi it's fully documented in the Javadoc that to subtract from a Calendar you use `add()` with a negative argument. So they didn't have a need to use `roll()` at all.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I know... I didn‘t write this piece of code.